# Still Can't Retrieve Element by Xpath/Text in Selenium Webdriverjs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I found a couple of other issues to fix in this, but I'm back to the spot I got to yesterday. I need to find a way to pick up these elements with only text. Eventually, everything will be rewritten to use ids.

When I inspect the element in FirePath, this is what I see. Pretty ugly, and this is a dynamic page, so the absolute position of the elements in this list are not guaranteed.

.//*[@id='v-Portlet_CCEditorApplicationportlet_WAR_Portlet_CCEditor_INSTANCE_n6EMyzyYmNu2_LAYOUT_22823']/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div

I have a document called MyTest. I'm trying to see if it's there:

```
driver.isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'MyTest')]")).then(function(foundit)
{
    if (foundit)
    {
        console.log('You forgot to delete your old document');
        driver.quit();
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Document Not there')
        driver.quit;
    }
});
```

Have also tried:

```
//div[contains(text(),'MyTest')
```

It doesn't seem to be in an iframe. I have tried switching to iframes 0 and 1.

Comment: Tried that, still can't find it.

Comment: you need to know how id generated. I think //*[contains(@id, 'CCEditorApplicationportlet')]//div[contains(.,'MyTest')] would work, but you better post 5-10 dynamic ID here, so we could have a better xpath suggestion.

Comment: and it will be better if you can give a link to the page or provide the complete HTML here.

Comment: I would love to do that, unfortunately, this application is not, and never will be, available on the internet, and the page is generated, and is 125,000 characters - I'm limited to 30,000 here.

Comment: Zipped up the file and saved it to Dropbox. Here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k6322h6cpqqzu3/problem_page.html.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Arg. Was using driver.wait, and until. They didn't work. The page was waiting. Finally used drive.sleep. It worked. I don't understand, but I can now move on.